# value prediction with tensorflow and python

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, bigdata

I have a data set which contains a list of stock prices. I need to use the tensorflow and python to predict the close price.

**Q1: I have the following code which takes the first 2000 records as training and 2001 to 20000 records as test but I don't know how to change the code to do the prediction of the close price of today and 1 day later??? Please advise!**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def feature_scaling(input_pd, scaling_meathod):
    if scaling_meathod == 'z-score':
       scaled_pd = (input_pd - input_pd.mean()) / input_pd.std()
    elif scaling_meathod == 'min-max':
       scaled_pd = (input_pd - input_pd.min()) / (input_pd.max() - 
    input_pd.min())
    return scaled_pd

def input_reshape(input_pd, start, end, batch_size, batch_shift, n_features):
    temp_pd = input_pd[start-1: end+batch_size-1]
    output_pd = map(lambda y : temp_pd[y:y+batch_size], xrange(0, end-start+1, batch_shift))
    output_temp = map(lambda x : np.array(output_pd[x]).reshape([-1]), xrange(len(output_pd)))
    output = np.reshape(output_temp, [-1, batch_size, n_features])
    return output

def target_reshape(input_pd, start, end, batch_size, batch_shift, n_step_ahead, m_steps_pred):
    temp_pd = input_pd[start+batch_size+n_step_ahead-2: end+batch_size+n_step_ahead+m_steps_pred-2]
    print temp_pd
    output_pd = map(lambda y : temp_pd[y:y+m_steps_pred], xrange(0, end-start+1, batch_shift))
    output_temp = map(lambda x : np.array(output_pd[x]).reshape([-1]), xrange(len(output_pd)))
    output = np.reshape(output_temp, [-1,1])
    return output

def lstm(input, n_inputs, n_steps, n_of_layers, scope_name): 
    num_layers = n_of_layers
    input = tf.transpose(input,[1, 0, 2])
    input = tf.reshape(input,[-1, n_inputs])  
    input = tf.split(0, n_steps, input)
    with tf.variable_scope(scope_name):
    cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=n_inputs) 
    cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([cell]*num_layers)
    output, state = tf.nn.rnn(cell, input, dtype=tf.float32)    yi1
    output = output[-1] 
    return output    

    feature_to_input = ['open price', 'highest price', 'lowest price', 'close price','turnover', 'volume','mean price']
    feature_to_predict = ['close price']
    feature_to_scale = ['volume']
    sacling_meathod = 'min-max'

    train_start = 1 
    train_end = 1000
    test_start = 1001
    test_end = 20000

    batch_size = 100
    batch_shift = 1
    n_step_ahead = 1
    m_steps_pred = 1
    n_features = len(feature_to_input)

    lstm_scope_name = 'lstm_prediction'
    n_lstm_layers = 1
    n_pred_class = 1
    learning_rate = 0.1
    EPOCHS = 1000
    PRINT_STEP = 100

    read_data_pd = pd.read_csv('./stock_price.csv')
    temp_pd = feature_scaling(input_pd[feature_to_scale],sacling_meathod)
    input_pd[feature_to_scale] = temp_pd
    train_input_temp_pd = input_pd[feature_to_input]
    train_input_nparr = input_reshape(train_input_temp_pd, 
    train_start, train_end, batch_size, batch_shift, n_features)

    train_target_temp_pd = input_pd[feature_to_predict]
    train_target_nparr = target_reshape(train_target_temp_pd, train_start, train_end, batch_size, batch_shift, n_step_ahead, m_steps_pred)

    test_input_temp_pd = input_pd[feature_to_input]
    test_input_nparr = input_reshape(test_input_temp_pd, test_start, test_end, batch_size, batch_shift, n_features)

    test_target_temp_pd = input_pd[feature_to_predict]
    test_target_nparr = target_reshape(test_target_temp_pd, test_start, test_end, batch_size, batch_shift, n_step_ahead, m_steps_pred)

    tf.reset_default_graph()

    x_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, batch_size, n_features])
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
    lstm_output = lstm(x_, n_features, batch_size, n_lstm_layers, lstm_scope_name)

    W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_features, n_pred_class]))                                                                                                    
    b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_pred_class]))
    y = tf.matmul(lstm_output, W) + b
    cost_func = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - y_))
    train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost_func)

    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)
    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()        
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)
        for ii in range(EPOCHS):
            sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={x_:train_input_nparr, y_:train_target_nparr})
            if ii % PRINT_STEP == 0:
               cost = sess.run(cost_func, feed_dict={x_:train_input_nparr, y_:train_target_nparr})
               print 'iteration =', ii, 'training cost:', cost
```

Comment: First of all, 90 is for training and 10 is for testing.

Comment: This question is a good example of the *damage* that such a great libraries like tensorflow are doing to the machine learning community. They make libraries so powerful that everyone expects to predict the future of the humanity with just 5 lines of code (and you can, if you *know* how to).

Comment: An omniscient being (i.e. the one who *knows* how to) doesn't even need 5 lines of code to predict the future of humanity :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q-1 : You should change your LSTM parameter to return a sequence of size two which will be prediction for that day and the day after.

Q-2 it's clearly that your model is [underfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting) the data, which is so obvious with your 10% train 90% test data ! You should more equilibrated ratio as suggested in the previous answer.

Answer (score 5):

Very simply, prediction (a.k.a. *scoring* or *inference*) comes from running the input through only the forward pass, and collecting the score for each input vector.  It's the same process flow as testing.  The difference is the four stages of model use:

1. Train: learn from the training data set; adjust weights as needed.
2. Test: evaluate the model's performance; if accuracy has converged, stop training.
3. Validate: evaluate the accuracy of the trained model.  If it doesn't meet acceptance criteria, change something and start over with the training.
4. Predict: you've passed validation -- release the model for use by the intended application.

All four steps follow the same forward logic flow; training includes back-propagation; the others do not.  Simply follow the forward-only process, and you'll get the result form you need.

I worry about your data partition: only 10% for training, 90% for testing, and none for validation.  A more typical split is 50-30-20, or something in that general area.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. Because I am new to tensorflow. Could you please edit the code to do the prediction such as 3 days later? And how to do the validation?

Comment: No; Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.  I gave you the approach; you should make the attack yourself.  If it doesn't work, post a question on that *specific* programming problem.

Comment: thanks for the comment. since the time column is dropped by the code, how can i predict the value of 1 day later?

Comment: another question is the code uses the parameters in parameters_to_input = ['open price', 'highest price', 'lowest price', 'close price','turnover', 'volume','mean price'] to predict the a column's value such as close price in the future. However,  how can i predict the close price without these parameters value in the future?

Comment: You don't, obviously: you train your model to predict the next *two* days, as a pair of values.

Comment: AFAIK, the standard terminology is Train -> Validate -> Test. Second, looping back to training after testing is problematic: Testing is meant to give you a realistic estimate of how the system will perform in real-world applications. If you use information from testing to improve your model, the set is not "unknown" any more and thus not a realistic proxy for the real world. In my opinion it is better to loop between training and validation, create a plurality of models and then use the one with the best performance on the test set.

Comment: @Igor: The flow of functionality in Caffe is training with internal test runs at long intervals (e.g. 1000 iterations), used to indicate convergence.  However, "test" is, indeed, an overloaded term: the prediction/scoring runs come under the Caffe **test** command -- so you're quite justified in using "test" that way.  My part of the DL world moved away from using "test" as a term during deployment.